# If preceding sibling node is one of these cakes

Tags: asp.net, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

My xml looks like this

```
<cakes>
   <chocolate>for Tom</chocolate>
   <vanilla>for Jim</vanilla>
   <strawberry>for Harry</strawberry>
   <vanilla>for Sue</vanilla>
</cake>
```

I'm looking for xslt that will work like this

```
<xsl:template match="vanilla">
   <xsl:if test="IF THE ELEMENT RIGHT BEFORE THIS ONE IS CHOCOLATE OR BLACKFOREST">
      <p>After a great cake <xsl:value-of select="chocolate | blackforest"/></p>
   </xsl:if>

   <p>There is a vanilla cake <xsl:value-of select="."/></p>
</xsl:template>
```

The output should be

```
After a great cake for Tom
There is a vanilla cake for Jim
There is a vanilla cake for Sue
```

I suspect the answer has to do with preceding-sibling::*[1], but i can't find how to then test if this is a specific node kind.

I'm developing in asp.net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I suspect the answer has to do with preceding-sibling::*[1], but i can't find how to then test if this is a specific node kind.

Yes, that is indeed the solution. You can test if a node is a specific element by checking the element name, which is `name()`<sup>1</sup>.

Note that this solution "reports" `chocolate` or `blackforest` elements only if they immediately precede a `vanilla` element. Also, it outputs text in a controlled way, only inside `xsl:text` elements. That is why line breaks must be explicitly added to the XSLT code.

**Stylesheet**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="vanilla">
        <xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::*[1][name() = 'chocolate' or name() = 'blackforest']">
            <xsl:text>After a great cake </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::*[1]"/>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:text>There is a vanilla cake </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
After a great cake for Tom
There is a vanilla cake for Jim
There is a vanilla cake for Sue
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Actually, `name()` returns the full, qualified name of an element. If an element is prefixed, the prefix will be returned, too. You can use `local-name()` to output only the "local" part of a qualified name.